# How to export hive query with a custom field separator

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table in hive 0.9 where the fields are \001 separated.
I have some of my fields containing tabulations.
As a result when I query my data using Hive on the command line:

```
hive -e "SELECT * FROM my_table" > output.tsv
```

I get extra columns in my output file.
In essence, I would like to be able to do something like

```
hive --output-field-separator '\001' -e "SELECT * FROM my_table"
```

Does anyone know a workaround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `INSERT OVERWRITE` instead [to write your data to a file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries). In Hive 0.9 you cannot change the separator using this method, but it looks like that [will be possible in a future release](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3682).

More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129581/how-do-i-output-the-results-of-a-hiveql-query-to-csv/18142190#18142190).

Hope that helps.