# Exporting Data from Hive table to Local Machine File System

Tags: hadoop, hive

Using following command:

```
insert overwrite local directory '/my/local/filesystem/directory/path'
select * from Emp;
```

overwrites the entire already existing data in `/my/local/filesystem/directory/path` with the data of Emp.

What i want is to ***just copy*** the data of Emp to `/my/loca/filesystem/directory/path` and ***not overwrite***, how to do that?

Following are my failed trials:

```
hive> insert into local directory '/home/cloudera/Desktop/Sumit' select * from appdata;
```

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:12 mismatched input 'local' expecting
>   TABLE near 'into' in insert clause

```
hive> insert local directory '/home/cloudera/Desktop/Sumit' select * from appdata;
```

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'insert'
>   'local' 'directory' in insert clause

Can u please tell me how can I get this solved?

Comment: I assume you've seen that if you export a lot of data it will end up in many different files. What behavior are you expecting? Why not just export to a new directory?

Answer (score 3):

To appened to a hive table you  need to use `INSERT INTO`:

> INSERT INTO will append to the table or partition keeping the existing
>   data in tact. (Note: INSERT INTO syntax is only available starting in
>   version 0.8)

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries

But you can't use this to append to an existing local file so another option is to use a bash command.

If you have a file called 'export.hql' and in that file your code is:

```
select * from Emp;
```

Then your bash command can be:

```
hive -f 'export.hql' >> localfile.txt
```

The -f command executes the hive file and the >> append pipes the results to the text file.

**EDIT**:

The command:

```
hive -f 'export.hql' > localfile.txt
```

Will save the hive query to a new file, not append.

Comment: We are "NOT TRYING TO APPEND" the data of Emp table to an existing table in Local File System. What we are trying is to  export data from a hive table (say, Emp)to an existing local file sysytem directory, without affecting the already existing contents of the directory.

Comment: See my edit for the command to export the Emp query to a file, not append.

Comment: This is one way. Is there any other way to do the same thing? using the INSERT..DIRECTORY command without the overwrite word.

Comment: have you tried your command "insert overwrite local directoy '/my/local/filesystem/directory/path' select * from Emp;". It should work, in your failed trials though you not implied you tried it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129581/how-do-i-output-the-results-of-a-hiveql-query-to-csv

Answer (score 0):

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-SQLOperations

When using 'LOCAL', 'OVERWRITE' is also needed in your hql.

For example: 
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/tmp/out' SELECT * FROM test