# How do I output the results of a HiveQL query to comma separated or pipe separated file?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Suppose we have a HIVE table like this

```
 name id age

 jones 12 34
 george joseph 13 45
 bush 15 23
```

Now i want to output this hive table to csv and pipe separated file. 
I followed steps in [How do I output the results of a HiveQL query to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129581/how-do-i-output-the-results-of-a-hiveql-query-to-csv).

```
 hive -e 'select books from table' | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/,/g' > /home/lvermeer/temp.csv
```

But its working this these

```
      name    id     age
      jones   12     34
      george  joseph 13  45
      bush    15     23
```

I want george joseph to be in 1 column. Since george joseph contains middle spaces, its outputting to next column. How to resolve this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

In case your query doesnt contain join or so criterias then You could easily get the data from the corresponding HDFS location. The data would be |(pipe) seperated as per the delimiters mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Hive columns are separated by '\t', assuming "george" and "joseph" are separated by space, you don't have any problems. You can check out separators with **vim**, just type `:set list`. Tabs would be marked as `^I`

To view output file, you can use, for example, LibreOffice Calc, but you have to be sure, that you are using as delimiters only tabs, not spaces