# Hive Query o/p to HDFS as CSV file

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

I want to write hive query output into HDFS file in CSV Format( comma separated).

**For LOCAL DIRECTORY:**

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/test/result/' 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' SELECT * from table;
```

Above Works fine and writes output of query as CSV Format in local directory.

**For HDFS:**

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/home/test/result/' SELECT * from table;
```

Output written to the HDFS is serialized as text with columns separated by ^A and rows separated by newlines.

**NOTE** :

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS  ---- Not supported for above query
```

Is there any way to write hive query output in HDFS directory as CSV file(comma separated)

Comment: Visit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129581/how-do-i-output-the-results-of-a-hiveql-query-to-csv

Comment: @GauravDave i want to write in HDFS file.. Not in local directory..Already checked above question

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way..
1. create a table as expected your result 
eg:create external table result(col1 type,col2 type,......)row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile location '/tmp/result';
2. import data to this table
eg:insert overwrite table result select * from tablename;
3.drop the external table
eg:drop table result;

On dropping external table only schema will be deleted data will remain in text file in specified directory which will be in comma separated format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/home/test/result/' SELECT concat(col1,',',col2,',', ...colN) from table;

Answer (score 0):

For writing data to hdfs in a custom format, use `printf`.

```
insert overwrite directory "youroutputdir"  select printf("%s,%s,%d", col1, col2, col3) from mytable;
```