# exporting Hive table to csv in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive

I know there is a known issue with delimiters when saving a table to csv (or other text file) in Hive.  So I'm wondering if you guys can help me get around that.

I have an existing table (Table A) and I would like to save it in csv format to hdfs.  From reading other responses I believe I would have to first create an external table (but I'm not sure how the whole thing would look).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Personally, I'd just use `insert overwrite directory` and have a `\001` delimited file.  But if you *must* have a csv, I think you're best off piping the query to a local .csv and then `hadoop fs -put`-ing it into hdfs, which is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129581/how-do-i-output-the-results-of-a-hiveql-query-to-csv

Comment: I want to avoid saving such a large file to the local directory if possible.  My issue is that I then need to load the file into R and to do this you normally specify a delimiter, not sure how this would work (or if it would work) with an invisible character.

Comment: I load data from hdfs to spark and specify the delimiter as `"\001"`.  I've never had (a reason) to import a file from HDFS to R but I'd assume it can take any delimiter as long as it is specified correctly.

Answer (score 12):

Try this in hive shell:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/path/to/hive/csv' ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' SELECT * FROM hivetablename;
```

Change your `/path/to/csv` to the location where you want to store csv file. `hivetablename` to your hive table to be stored in csv format.

Comment: I think that she wants it saved on hdfs, not on the local fs.

Comment: @KimMoritz In that case, excluding `LOCAL` and specifying the HDFS path should do the trick.

Comment: i got this error `Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Failed to create local target directory /export`

Answer (score 4):

This three step process worked fine for me:

1. **in HIVE**, create a new temporary table stored as textfile

   ```
   CREATE TABLE temp_table( id INT, name STRING)
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   STORED AS TEXTFILE;
   ```
2. also **in HIVE**, write the source data into the temporary table

   ```
   INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE temp_table
   SELECT id, name FROM source_table;
   ```
3. From the command line, copy the Hive table from its location in HDFS to you local file - inspection should reveal the file as csv (rename accordingly if desired)

   ```
   hdfs dfs -copyToLocal /apps/hive/warehouse/temp_table/* /tmp/local_dir/
   ```

If you run the command `SHOW CREATE TABLE temp_table` **in HIVE**, it will tell you the exact location of the table in HDFS, e.g.

```
| LOCATION                                                        |
|   'hdfs://hadoop_cluster/apps/hive/warehouse/temp_table'        |
```

Answer (score 1):

For external table in hive, you can follow the below steps:

1. **Create external table in hive**

   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE external_table( number INT, name STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/user/hive/external/mytable/';

**2. Load the data file from local to HDFS location**

```
hadoop fs -put /home/user1/Desktop/filename.csv /user/hive/external/mytable/
```

The above two steps can solve your problem.

Comment: where am I inputting the existing table that I have created? I see this as creating a blank table and putting it in the local directory.  Can you explain more?

Comment: LOCATION '/user/hive/external/mytable/'; the location value is the HDFS location directory and NOT local directory. while moving the file i.e. hadoop fs -put /home/user1/Desktop/filename.csv /user/hive/external/mytable/ , it is from local directory to HDFS location directory

Comment: my table is already stored in hdfs and can be accessed with a /user/hive... path

Comment: If you can access the csv file data using select query and open the csv file using hadoop fs -cat 'file-path'  correctly, then now move the csv file to the required location where you want.

Answer (score 0):

3 steps you may follow:-

1. Create a temporary table

   `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test;
    CREATE TABLE Test 
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' AS
    SELECT * FROM ABC #OR whole query statements`
2. Make a `CSV` from created hive table

   `hive -e 'set hive.cli.print.header=true; select * from Test' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > /home/hadoop/Mycsv.csv`
3. Put the created `CSV` file to S3 of whatever location you want

   `hdfs dfs -put -f /home/hadoop/Mycsv.csv 's3://bucketName/'`