# How do I save the result of a Hive query to the filesystem with headers?

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I read through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129581/how-do-i-output-the-results-of-a-hiveql-query-to-csv), which is essentially what I'm trying to do.
For a couple of reasons this approach seems to most straighforward for my need:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestHiveTableCSV; 
CREATE TABLE TestHiveTableCSV 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' AS
 SELECT Column List FROM TestHiveTable;
```

However when I move that file from HDFS onto my local filesysyem I lose the headers. Any idea how to add headers?

Answer (score 1):

use `set hive.cli.print.header=true;`

usage

```
hive -S -e ' set hive.cli.print.header=true;select * from table ' >> outputfile
```

Or you can use this approach as well

> hive -f  ${HIVEFILE1} -hiveconf hive_database=${HIVE_DATABASE}
>   -hiveconf CURRENT_DATE='2014-05-05' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > yourfile.csv

where Hivefile1 has the hive query "set hive.cli.print.header=true;select * from table"

Comment: hive -S -e ' set hive.cli.print.header=true;select * from table ' >> outputfile

Comment: Or you can use this approach as well

 hive -f  ${HIVEFILE1} -hiveconf hive_database=${HIVE_DATABASE} -hiveconf CURRENT_DATE='2014-05-05' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > yourfile.csv

where Hivefile1 has the hive query "set hive.cli.print.header=true;select * from table"

Comment: If I follow the initial suggestion "hive -S -e..." the file created is no longer a comma separated.