# How to export results into excel files from an individual query when running multiple queries in Toad 4 Hadoop

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, toad

I am attempting to run all these queries (only part of the 2000 total) and need to export the results from each into their own excel file. Is there a way to automate this with an export function?

```
select * from Finance.ACCT_LIST limit 1000
select * from Finance.ACCTG_REV_DLY_AGG_F limit 1000
select * from Finance.ACQ_SHIP_F limit 1000
select * from Finance.ACQ_SO_F limit 1000
select * from Finance.ACQUISITION limit 1000
select * from Finance.ACTY limit 1000
select * from Sales.ADDR_CTRY_LANG limit 1000
select * from Common_Dimensions_Finance.ADJ limit 1000
select * from Finance.ADJ_CD_SRC_SYS limit 1000
select * from Common_Dimensions_Finance.ADJ_D limit 1000
select * from Supply_Chain.ADV_SHIP_NOTIF limit 1000
select * from Supply_Chain.ADV_SHIP_NOTIF_ITM limit 1000
select * from Common_Dimensions_Supply_Chain.ADV_SHIP_NOTIF_ITM_D limit 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

The default output format of Hive query is tsv.
If thats good enough for u then a possible solution is to create a bash script (.sh) as follows:

```
hive -e "select * from Finance.ACCT_LIST limit 1000" > rs_1.tsv
hive -e "select * from Finance.ACCTG_REV_DLY_AGG_F limit 1000" > rs_2.tsv
hive -e "select * from Finance.ACQ_SHIP_F limit 1000" > rs_3.tsv
hive -e "select * from Finance.ACQ_SO_F limit 1000" > rs_4.tsv
hive -e "select * from Finance.ACQUISITION limit 1000" > rs_5.tsv
hive -e "select * from Finance.ACTY limit 1000" > rs_6.tsv
    .
    .
    .
```

Then copy all the csv files to your local and open them with Excel.

Otherwise check [How do I output the results of a HiveQL query to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129581/how-do-i-output-the-results-of-a-hiveql-query-to-csv)

All the above is assuming you can connect to the cluster's master.