# How to export hive data to csv or txt

Tags: sql, csv, hive, bigdata

how to export hive into a csv or txt in a big data, the data are more than 10000, and i use hue browser to export it.

i already tried insert overwrite local directory code, but it didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export a Hive table into a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086642/how-to-export-a-hive-table-into-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/tmp/dir/file1'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
SELECT * from tablename;
```

come out of hive cli

go to this /tmp/dir/ location

cat file1/* > file1.csv

zip file1 file1.csv

winscp it to windows and enjoy :)

Comment: is that can use in hue? or must use in hive cli?

Comment: Insert overwrite can be written in hue. Once the query is completed km hue, then go to Unix cli to check the folder

Comment: in /tmp/dir/file1, which one should i change the name?

Comment: Change the name as in?? You can put whatever location you want to.

Comment: i've tried to use the code above, but it was error
thee statement is : Error while compiling statement:FAILED: ParseException line 2:43 cannot recognize input near ',' 'select''*'in statement

Comment: It ran for me fine. Can you check if there is any junk character while you're copy-pasting it. If possible, type in everything manually in hive cli and you should be able to run successfully.

Comment: okay, it works. but i still can't open  /tmp/dir/ location . how should i do?

Comment: Apologies I cannot spoon feed you on everything. Chrck my answer and try to figure it out.

Comment: okay, thank you for your answer. but i stll can't open my directory

Answer (score 0):

You can query your data from the command line as such:

hive -e 'select x from table1' > /your/directory/data.csv

Refer to this solution for more info:

[How do I output the results of a HiveQL query to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18129581/how-do-i-output-the-results-of-a-hiveql-query-to-csv)