# im install hive bug query have |,how to solve it?

Tags: hive

im install ambari then install hive,but when i use it,like this:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://master.ambari:2181,slave1.amb>
```

The correct display should be

```
hive>
```

and other err

```
0: jdbc:hive2://master.ambari:2181,slave1.amb> select 1,2,3;
+------+------+------+
| _c0  | _c1  | _c2  |
+------+------+------+
| 1    | 2    | 3    |
+------+------+------+
1 row selected (0.221 seconds)
```

The correct display should be

```
hive>select 1,2,3;
1   2   3
```

How do we deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> The correct display should be

No, `beeline` should be used instead of `hive` command, and will result in the full connection URI displayed.

If you want to turn the frames off, then you can use

```
>!set showheader false;
>select 1,2,3;
```

Comment: Hello, how can I eliminate this border？

Comment: yes,I tried, but I only got rid of the header, not the border。

Comment: Did you try `--outputformat csv2`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56075606/2308683